# Extract next line after match in regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a image based multiple page pdfs and i have to extract a line that contains  EPC and the next line associate with it

Example:

```
ENERGY PERFORMANCE CERTIFICATE
D(139)
```

I tried this code:

```
import os    
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import re

poppler_path = "C:/Users/poddaral/temp/poppler-0.68.0/bin"
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:/Users/poddaral/temp/tesseract.exe"

pdf_path = "C:/Users/poddaral/temp/4-6 Etloe Road, Westbury Park, Bristol, BS6 7PF.pdf"

images = convert_from_path(pdf_path=pdf_path, poppler_path=poppler_path)

for count, img in enumerate(images):
  img_name = f"page_{count}.png"  
  img.save(img_name, "PNG")

png_files = [f for f in os.listdir(".") if f.endswith(".png")]

for png_file in png_files:
  extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(png_file))
  print(extracted_text)



pattern = re.compile('ENERGY PERFORMANCE CERTIFICATE')

def find_following_line(extracted_text):
    lines = extracted_text.splitlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if re.search(pattern, line):
            return lines[i+2]

print(find_following_line(extracted_text))
```

Comment: Why is the code you posted "not working"? What unexpected results did it give you, and why was it unexpected to you?

Comment: Why `i+2` instead of `i+1`? What is the specific question/problem?

Comment: getting the output as None

Comment: Please, clarify what is the problem you are getting. What does not work in this code?

Comment: Maybe a typo in the pattern? Have you tried to just copy and paste the "ENERGY PERFORMANCE..." from the file into the code as regex pattern?

Comment: Michael Butscher yes tried with that too getting output as none only.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your index from 2 to 1 and this gives exactly what you search:

```
import re

extracted_text="""ENERGY PERFORMANCE CERTIFICATE
D(139)"""
print(repr(extracted_text))

pattern = re.compile('ENERGY PERFORMANCE CERTIFICATE')

def find_following_line(extracted_text):
    lines = extracted_text.splitlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if re.search(pattern, line):
            return lines[i+1] # 2 changed to 1

print(find_following_line(extracted_text))
```

Gives me this output:

```
'ENERGY PERFORMANCE CERTIFICATE\nD(139)'
D(139)
```

Comment: I have a 30 page of image pdf converted them to text and i want only the energy performance certificate form that extracted text

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = fp.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if re.search(pattern, line):
                    print (line)
                    print (lines[i+1])
```

A small change in your function `def find_following_line(extracted_text):` with your index will work

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid counting the lines, just return the current line if the previous line matched

```
import re

extracted_text = '''\
ppweiopo
epjijorerg
ENERGY PERFORMANCE CERTIFICATE
D(139)
owiffoij
oidevjoij
'''

# ffl stands for "find following line"
def ffl(text, pattern, out=None):
    for line in text.splitlines():
        if out: return line
        out = re.search(pattern, line)

print(ffl(extracted_text, '^ENERGY PERFORMANCE CERTIFICATE$')) ###> D(139)
```

If someone else wants to ***sometimes*** return the matching line too,

```
def ffl(text, pattern, both=False, out=False):
    for line in text.splitlines():
        if out: return prevline+'\n'+line if both else line
        out = re.search(pattern, line)
        if out and both: prevline = line
```